# iOS Address Book: Can a person record have a nil first name?

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

If a contact's first name or last name is blank, will the value be `nil` or `""`?

Answer (score 2):

The value will be `nil` as of Xcode 6 Beta 4.

To see for yourself, run the following code twice:

```
// AppDelegate.swift

import AddressBookUI
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow!

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        let addressBookTemp = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error)
        if !addressBookTemp {
            println(error)
            return true
        }

        let addressBook = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(addressBookTemp.toOpaque()).takeRetainedValue()
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, nil)

        var allPeople: NSArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue()
        println("allPeople.count: \(allPeople.count)")

        for person in allPeople {
            let firstNameTemp = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)
            let firstName: NSObject! = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(firstNameTemp.toOpaque()).takeRetainedValue()

            if firstName {
                println("firstName: \(firstName)")
            } else {
                println("fristName is nil")
            }

            let lastNameTemp = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)
            let lastName: NSObject! = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(lastNameTemp.toOpaque()).takeRetainedValue()

            if lastName {
                println("lastName: \(lastName)")
            } else {
                println("lastName is nil")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a person don't have first or last name the value will be `nil`.
If you want to cast it to an empty string you can do this:

```
            // Getting the first and the last name of person
        let firstNameTemp = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?;
        let firstName: NSObject? = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(firstNameTemp!.toOpaque()).takeRetainedValue();
        var first_name = "";
        if firstName != nil {
            first_name = firstName! as NSString;
        }

        let lastNameTemp = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)?;
        let lastName: NSObject? = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(lastNameTemp!.toOpaque()).takeRetainedValue();
        var last_name = "";
        if lastName != nil {
            last_name = lastName! as NSString;
        }
```

Comment: That is correct, and you would think there is some shorter Swift syntax for this. But firstNameTemp is not an Optional, even though it could be nil. But if anyone has a more concise way to do it, I'd love to see it.